# Is it possible to use all Google Maps feature with Leaflet's GoogleMutant API

Tags: javascript, leaflet, google-maps-api, google-street-view

I'm using leaflet in my project for longer period of time.  Now it is required to use [Street View](https://goo.gl/bs3W7F) feature of google map with it's Peg Men.

Is it feasible?

I've another question in mind where will I be allowed to consume all the feature google map's provide via Leaflet GoogleMutant API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GoogleMutant developer here.

No, it's not possible. GoogleMutant is meant to provide a reliable (and ToC-compliant) way of loading GMap's tiles into Leaflet, nothing more.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.  It would be helpful to fellow developers in future if you add this information in github page.

Comment: Feel free to go to https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.GridLayer.GoogleMutant/blob/master/README.md and propose a change.